# ORA-19279: XPTY0004 - XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton sequence - different case

Tags: xml, oracle

I have some problem trying to select some fields from an `XML` file in `Oracle`.

I'm getting the error below:

> ORA-19279: XPTY0004 - XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton sequence - got multi-item sequence

The **XML structure** is like:

```
<REC r_id_disclaimer="yyyyyyy">
   <UID>xxxxxxx</UID>
   <static_data>
   <keywords count="4">
       <keyword>Brain-</keyword>
       <keyword>Depres</keyword>
       <keyword>Acute</keyword>
       <keyword>Chine</keyword>
   </keywords>
```

The **query** I'm using is the below:

```
select RecUid.CD_UID
     , Abst2.*
from testtable2 t
cross join  xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://scientific.thomsonreuters.com/schema/wok5.4/public/FullRecord'),
 'records/REC'
  passing t.xml_file 
  columns     CD_UID varchar2(200) path 'UID',
              --names xmltype path 'static_data/summary'
              Abstract xmltype path 'static_data/fullrecord_metadata'
            ) RecUid


cross join xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://scientific.thomsonreuters.com/schema/wok5.4/public/FullRecord'),
 'keywords/keywords'
  passing RecUid.Abstract

  columns     keyword varchar2(200) path 'keyword'
            ) as Abst2
    ;
```

I've read all the others topics related to the same error, but I cannot find a solution for my case. I've tried with

```
columns     keyword varchar2(200) path 'keyword()'
or
columns     keyword varchar2(200) path 'keyword/text()'
or
columns     keyword varchar2(200) path '//*keyword()'
and
columns     keyword varchar2(200) path '/.keyword'
```

We are running the:
    `Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition     11.2.0.4.0  64bit Production`

Can somebody help me to find the error?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the expected output for the above xml? Also, could you update your sample xml to be correct and valid xml that can be used to run your query against? (eg. there is no end tag for <REC>, and there is no mention of <records> in the sampl xml, yet there is in the query)

Comment: `<records><REC r_id_disclaimer="yyyyyyy">
   <UID>xxxxxxx</UID>
   <static_data>
   <keywords count="4">
       <keyword>Brain-</keyword>
       <keyword>Depres</keyword>
       <keyword>Acute</keyword>
       <keyword>Chine</keyword>
   </keywords> </rec></records>`

Comment: The expected output are 2 columns: the CD_UID and the related keywords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After tweaking your xml data a lot, and commenting out the namespace bit (which made it return no rows for me), I managed to get the output I think you're after:

```
with testtable2 as (select xmltype(
'<records>
  <REC r_id_disclaimer="yyyyyyy">
     <UID>xxxxxxx</UID>
     <static_data>
       <keywords count="4">
           <keyword>Brain</keyword>
           <keyword>Depres</keyword>
           <keyword>Acute</keyword>
           <keyword>Chine</keyword>
       </keywords>
     </static_data>
  </REC>
</records>') xml_file from dual)
select RecUid.CD_UID,
       Abst2.*
from   testtable2 t
       cross join xmltable(--xmlnamespaces(default 'http://scientific.thomsonreuters.com/schema/wok5.4/public/FullRecord'),
                           'records/REC'
                           passing t.xml_file 
                           columns CD_UID varchar2(200) path 'UID',
                                   --names xmltype path 'static_data/summary'
                                   Abstract xmltype path 'static_data/keywords'
                           ) RecUid
       cross join xmltable(--xmlnamespaces(default 'http://scientific.thomsonreuters.com/schema/wok5.4/public/FullRecord'),
                           'keywords/keyword'
                           passing RecUid.Abstract
                           columns keyword varchar2(200) path '.'
                           ) Abst2;

CD_UID               KEYWORD             
-------------------- --------------------
xxxxxxx              Brain               
xxxxxxx              Depres              
xxxxxxx              Acute               
xxxxxxx              Chine
```